# A more elegant way of writing repetitive code (template)?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a block of code in which there are multiple times the same kind of operations:

```
void fn() {
  if (params[0].count("VARIABLE_1"))
  {
     STRUCT.VARIABLE_1= boost::lexical_cast<VARIABLE_1_TYPE>(params[0].at("VARIABLE_1"));
  }
  if (params[0].count("VARIABLE_2"))
  {
     STRUCT.VARIABLE_2 = boost::lexical_cast<VARIABLE_2_TYPE>(params[0].at("VARIABLE_2"));
  }
  // many times this kind of if (...) with different parameters
}
```

Pretty sure there's a more elegant way of writing this in modern C++ (11, 17, 20) using templates I assume. Any idea?

**Edit**: only the `VARIABLE_n` and `VARIABLE_n_TYPE` change, `params[0]` stays as is.

Comment: Which parameters are different? That's a very important detail

Comment: Which parts are repeating? Is is `params[n]` or `count(SOME_LITERAL)`? or both?

Comment: `for` loop? We need more details. Can you add additional example statements?

Comment: Is `params[0]` a `map<string, string>`, or something different?

Comment: `// many times this kind of if (...) with different parameters` -- Unfortunately, we cannot expand this macro-comment mentally.  This could mean anything -- please post the actual examples of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want something as both an identifier in code, and as a string literal, you either repeat yourself

```
template<typename T, typename Map>
void extract_param(T & t, const Map & map, std::string name) {
    if (auto it = params.find(name); it != params.end()) {
        t = boost::lexical_cast<T>(*it);
    }
}

void fn() {
    extract_param(STRUCT.VARIABLE, params[0], "VARIABLE");
    // ...
}
```

or use a macro

```
#define EXTRACT_PARAM(Key) if (auto it = params[0].find(#Key); it != params[0].end()) { \
    STRUCT.Key = boost::lexical_cast<decltype(STRUCT.Key)>(*it); \
}

void fn() {
    EXTRACT_PARAM(VARIABLE)
    // ...
}

#UNDEF EXTRACT_PARAM
```